# Encrypting data written to an LVM snapshot with a different key

Tags: lvm, luks, snapshot

I have the following requirements:

- I have an LVM volume `A`, encrypted with key `K1` using LUKS.
- I need to make a copy-on-write snapshot of `A` such that

  - Writes to `A` will continue to be encrypted under `K1`
  - Writes to the *snapshot* will be encrypted under `K2`, which is different from `K1`.

The use case is to allow the snapshot to be securely deleted by deleting the encryption key.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to change the LUKS encryption key when making an LVM snapshot.

LUKS is unaware of LVM, so this would be no different than cloning a partition and expecting to be able to change the encryption key.

Now, you **MAY** be able to achieve your goal if you flip LVM and LUKS. It's a complex setup that goes something like this:

1. Create multiple LUKS containers in partitions, each with a different key, of course.
2. Create an LVM volume group which uses the unlocked LUKS containers as physical volumes.
3. When you create logical volumes, specify which physical volume to use; This will determine which LUKS key is used for the logical volume.
4. When you create a snapshot, specify a different physical volume; This means writes to this volume would be encrypted with a different LUKS key.